# MySQL Conditional Group By BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the below table. I want to aggregate a few columns and `GROUP BY` `store`. The issue is if the `upc` is negative and there is a corresponding positive `upc` I  want it to always select the positive number. If there is not corresponding positive `upc` then keeping the negative is fine. Also when I try to run a similar query on Google BigQuery (which to my understanding uses MySQL) 
 and leave out `upc` from the `GROUP BY` I get a error "SELECT list expression references column upc which is neither grouped nor aggregated". Any idea why BigQuery is behaving differently than MySQL workbench and how to force the query to always take the positive `upc`?

Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE upc (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
store  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
amount DOUBLE,
total INT,
upc INT
);

INSERT INTO upc (store, amount, total, upc) VALUES
    ('123', 12.3, 1, 123),
    ('123', 45.6, 2, -666),
    ('789', 78.9, 3, 789),
    ('789', 78.9, 3, 789),
    ('456', 78.9, 3, -456),
    ('456', 78.9, 3, -456),
    ('123', 78.9, 3, 123);

SELECT store, SUM(amount), SUM(total), upc FROM upc 
GROUP BY store;
```

Comment: If there are multiple positive `upc` values for a `store`; you want to select any one of them ?

Comment: There will never be more than a single positive `upc`

Comment: And, what if there are mutliple negative values ? Do you care which one to be picked ? If no, Elliott's solution should be enough and you should consider marking it as accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, negative values don't matter. I did in fact go with Elliot's solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery does not use MySQL. If you want a positive value of `upc`, then compute the `MAX` of the column:

```
SELECT store, SUM(amount), SUM(total), MAX(upc)
FROM upc 
GROUP BY store;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variation is in using ANY_VALUE() instead of MAX() to eliminate computing the MAX function, which incurs an extra cost - this can apply to really high volume'd data. On small data this might be not even visible

```
#standardSQL
SELECT store, SUM(amount), SUM(total), ANY_VALUE(upc)
FROM `project.dataset.upc`
GROUP BY store
```